# Get Office 365 Group Audit log details through GraphAPI

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, audit

I'm trying to use GraphAPI to gather Audit logs for any Add-DistributionGroupMember or Remove-DistributionGroup member activities for last 30 days. I'm specifically looking for the identity of the user who was added/removed from the DL. The name of the DL. The Account triggering the addition/removal request and timestamp.
[image: Pic1]

Now i do get some result, but it does not show the Distribution list from where user was added/remove and the name/identity of the user who made the request. How can i get this info. using Graph API?
[image: Pic2]